# Dotnet docker mongodb doesn't respond

Tags: .net, mongodb, docker

I have a dotnet project that runs docker compose and dockerized api and mongodb, I have debugged that the call goes into the collection to call ToListAsync() but nothing happens sometimes if I am lucky I get an empty Exception (not even MongoException type). Couldn't find any errors in logs.
My Repository looks like this:

```
public class EventRepository : IEventRepository {
private readonly IMongoCollection\<Event\> \_events;

public EventRepository(IOptions\<DatabaseSettings\> dbConfig) {
var client = new MongoClient(dbConfig.Value.ConnectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase(dbConfig.Value.DatabaseName);
\_events = database.GetCollection\<Event\>(dbConfig.Value.EventsCollectionName); }

public async Task\<List\<Event\>\> GetEventListAsync() {
try {
return await _events.Find(_ =\> true).ToListAsync();
}
catch (MongoException ex) {
throw;
}
}
```

....

`My program.cs looks like this`
`var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`

`// Add services to the container.`

`builder.Services.AddControllers();`
``` // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at ``https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle ```
`builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();`
`builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();`
`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();`
`builder.Services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection"));`
`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEventService, EventService>();`

...........

And this is my docker-compose related to mongodb

```
 mongodb:
   container_name: event-db
   image: mongo:latest
   ports:
       - "27017:27017"  # Map container port 27017 to host port 27017 (adjust as needed)
   volumes:
       - mongo-data:/data/db  # Mount a volume for MongoDB data (adjust as needed)
```

```
volumes:
  mongo-data:  
  keycloak-db-data:
```

This is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "MongoConnection": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "EventAppDb",
    "EventsCollectionName": "Events"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I also use traefik if that does change anything but I don't think so.
I feel like I have tried anything I haven't done a typo either.
Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For connecting to the other container, you can't use `localhost` in your connection string, you need to use the service name `mongodb`. See the [compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much this was what I needed... I must have overlooked.